# Android SPen SDK retrieve hovering points

Tags: android, hover, samsung-mobile

Good day,

I need to retrieve all points (including the points picked up when the stylus is not touching) using the SPen.

I've managed to retrieve the points, pressure and timestamps from the getObjectList from the PageDoc, see snippit below, but these does not include the hovering points.

```
        ArrayList<SpenObjectBase> objs = mSpenPageDoc.getObjectList();
        for (SpenObjectBase obj:objs)
        {
            if(obj.getType() == SpenObjectBase.TYPE_STROKE)
            {
                SpenObjectStroke stroke = (SpenObjectStroke)obj;
                PointF[] points = stroke.getPoints();
                float[] pressurePoints = stroke.getPressures();
                int[] time = stroke.getTimeStamps();

                for(int i=0;i<points.length;++i)
                {
                    if(pressurePoints[i] > 0)
                    {
                        //DO STUFF
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //This is never called
                        Log.i(TAG, "PRESSURE = 0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there some other Object I need to check for to be able to access all points, not just where the stylus touches the surface?

Regards,
Magda

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a function that will return all captured points (including the hovering points). I resolved this by registering for the onTouch and onHover event listener on the SpenView and storing all the points from there, as in the snippet below.

```
OnTouchListener onMyTouchEvent = new OnTouchListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMyTouchEvent");
        createPoint(event.getX(),event.getY(),event.getPressure());
        return mSpenView.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

};

OnHoverListener onMyHoverEvent = new OnHoverListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMyHoverEvent");
        createPoint(event.getX(),event.getY(),event.getPressure());
        return mSpenView.onHoverEvent(event);
    }

};
```